# How to tell notepad++ regular expression to be non greedy?

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

I'd like to test my regular expressions in notepad++ before I let em play outside the box. The expression itself works but it should be tell to be non greedy. Though I know how to do this in PHP I've got no clue how to do this in notepad.

My expression:

```php
(#([^\]]+))?stop_here\?([^\]]+)
```

I would do this in PHP like this using the u-modifier:

```php
preg_match_all("/(#([^\]]+))?stop_here\?([^\]]+)/U", $input_string, $result_array);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding a `?` after quantifiers `?`, `+` or `*`, they becomes non-greedy:

```
(#([^\]]+?))??stop_here\??([^\]]+?)
```

[Also works in PCRE PHP functions like preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php)

Answer (score 2):

As TwiNight wrote you must add a question mark after each quantifier.

Notice that if you want to test your php regex before let em play outside the box, the best way is to use a regex tester **for PHP** (for example:http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm or another). Notepad++ is very limited to do that.

Keep in mind that non-greedy quantifiers are slow (because the regex engine do many backtracks). You should avoid them when it's possible. You could use the faster possessive quantifiers too (but not with notepad++).

Comment: Good to know about the performance but in this case it's not realtime code but used to pregenerate something localy so don't worry about it ;)